# Can Gson handle Lists that were initialized inline

Tags: java, json, gson

Gson fails to handle lists that were initialized inline, as follows:

```
@Test
public void cannot_serialize(){
    List<String> items = new ArrayList(){{
        add("a");
        add("s");
    }};
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(items.getClass());
}

@Test
public void cannot_serialize_with_cast(){
    List<String> items = (ArrayList<String>)new ArrayList(){{
        add("a");
        add("s");
    }};
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(items.getClass());
}
```

The output of these two test is here:

```
null
class tests.tradio.GsonTests$1
null
class tests.tradio.GsonTests$2
```

I guess that the messed up class type causes Gson to ignore the list. Of course, without inline initialization everything works:

```
@Test
public void serializes(){
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("a");
    items.add("s");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(items.getClass());
}

["a","s"]
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Is there a way to have Gson handle inline initialized lists?

Comment: there are better ways of initializing your lists. `Arrays.asList` for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList(){{
    add("a");
    add("s");
}};
```

is an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`.

[`Gson`, by default, excludes anonymous classes from being serialized.](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/298) This is determined within `Excluder`, if you're interested in how it does it.

You could do this with Jackson if you wanted to.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList() {
    {
        add("a");
        add("s");
    }
};
ObjectMapper gson = new ObjectMapper();
String json = gson.writeValueAsString(items);
System.out.println(json);
```

But honestly, don't use these "hacks" for creating your `ArrayList` objects or other collection types.

Comment: If the common approach is "don't use these "hacks" for creating your ArrayList objects or other collection types", then these hacks should be removed from the language altogether, right?

Comment: @AlexC This is just one use of anonymous classes (to take advantage of instance initializers). There are other uses for anonymous classes.

Comment: Being able to use initializers in anonymous classes can be useful sometimes, but it is not a good idea to use them for Lists or other collections. Some IDEs can be configured to produce a warning or error, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Gson is not able to identify the class type and that's why it's printing null. A *hack* would be to wrap this list into another list, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("a");
        add("s");
    }});
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(items.getClass());
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` would probably be nicer here, rather than creating a new anonymous class.